# Nexus 3 Pro - View role membership/allocation

Tags: ldap, nexus, roles

Is there a way to see what role has been assigned to either local and remote (LDAP) users. For example, I want to see which users in an LDAP infrastructure have the nx-admin role assigned.

I've been looking via google and in the Nexus documentation, but haven't had much luck yet. I know I can check to see if a specific user has a role, but this isn't a scalable solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no current way to do this. File an issue at: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS if you would, this sounds like a logical piece of functionality :)